# How to use SQL conditional statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements

I need to delete a row based upon the value in a column while executing an update query. Here is the code:

```
 UPDATE tag SET tag_count = tag_count - 1 WHERE tag_id = 1
 IF tag_count < 1
 delete from tag where tag_id = 1
```

This query here gives me an error.

**EDIT**
I am using inline sql with C# and sql server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, the best option in these cases is to wrap the UPDATE and DELETE statements within a transaction:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE tag SET tag_count = tag_count - 1 WHERE tag_id = 1
DELETE from tag where tag_id = 1 and tag_count < 1;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: Good answer, it is always best to avoid a procedural approach when a declarative one is available. Use conditionals and other control flow structures only as a last resort in a stored procedure.

Comment: @Luke101: Yes sure, it will work. Since you are using C#, you may want to check this short example which uses a similar transaction to yours: http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/database/sql-transaction-csharp.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, did you try using Begin and End?

```
 UPDATE tag 
 SET tag_count = tag_count - 1 
 WHERE tag_id = 1

 IF tag_count < 1
     BEGIN
       DELETE FROM tag 
       WHERE tag_id = 1
     END
```

Comment: In this case, you would still need to `SELECT tag_count FROM tag WHERE tag_id=1` before the condition statement. However this is not necessary since you can easily specify the condition in the `DELETE` statement.

Comment: sql server does not recognize "tag_count" in the IF conditional as a valid column when I tried this code.